# In git2-rs, how do I authenticate when cloning?

Tags: authentication, rust, git-clone, libgit2

How do I pass an authentication callback to `git2::Repository::clone()`? (`set_remote_callbacks` sets up the callbacks).

I have some code like the following:

```rust
let mut cb = git2::RemoteCallbacks::new();
Self::set_remote_callbacks(&mut cb);
let rr = Repository::clone(url, path.to_str().ok_or("bad string".to_string())?);
```

What I want is like, as an example, when I do I fetch, I do this, which passes my callbacks to the `fetch`:

```rust
let mut fetchOptions = FetchOptions::new();
let mut cb = git2::RemoteCallbacks::new();
Self::set_remote_callbacks(&mut cb);
fetchOptions.remote_callbacks(cb);
let mut remote = self.repo.find_remote(remote)?;
remote.fetch(&[branch], Some(&mut fetchOptions), None)?;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `git2::build::RepoBuilder`.

Credit goes to [issue 329 on the git2 issue tracker](https://github.com/rust-lang/git2-rs/issues/329).